# Monitor folder in AWS ec2 instance with Bash or Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, amazon-ec2, data-transfer

I would like to set up file monitor agent at my local server and constantly monitoring file generation in a AWS EC2 folder, if a file is generated in a AWS EC2 folder, the file monitor agent will identify and instantly download it to my local server. The flow looks like:

1. file agent monitoring AWS EC2 folderA from local server
2. a file is output to AWS EC2 folderA
3. file agent identifies there's a file in folderA
4. file agent download the file from AWS EC2 folderA to local server
5. file agent continue monitor if new files are output to AWS EC2 folderA and download them.

I am new to such automatic data monitoring and transferring, just happy to learn if there's any recommended libraries/syntax/methods in python and bash? Thanks.

Comment: The code would need to be running on the EC2 server to monitor the folder. It wouldn't be "downloading the file to your local server" it would be uploading the file. Is your local server accessible via something like SSH/SFTP? In other words, how can the EC2 instance connect to the local server?

Comment: I would encourage you to re-think your architecture. It would be easier to have a script ('agent') running on the EC2 instance itself. When a new file is generated, the agent could copy the file to an Amazon S3 bucket (which is _much_ easier than attempting to copy it to a server somewhere). You could then have a separate process that does something with the files in the S3 bucket.

Comment: What is your actual end-to-end requirement? Can you change the system that is generating files on the EC2 instance and have it create files elsewhere? What is the software that is generating those files? What do you intend to do with the files after you have transferred them to the 'local server'? How will those files be used, or what other purpose do you have for those files (eg is it just for backup, or will they actually be processed somehow)?